# Problemas websocket, apache proxy_wstunnel, AWS

Tags: apache2, aws, websocket

He configurado un `websocket` en un `EC2` pero no puedo iniciar el protocolo.

Me da los siguientes errores:

```
[Thu Jun 07 14:04:45.363660 2018] [proxy:warn] [pid 9008] [client *****:37376] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /ws2/server.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu Jun 07 14:04:48.114988 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 9209] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to (IP publica de aws):59001 (dominio.com) failed
[Thu Jun 07 14:04:48.115025 2018] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 9209] [client *****:37458] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: dominio.com
```

Al intentar lanzar el websocket directamente desde comandos:

sudo php -q server.php

recibo el siguiente error:

> PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot
>   assign requested address in
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/ws2/class.PHPWebSocket.php on line
>   110

¿Alguien con el mismo problema?

Comment: habilitastes  el mod_proxy?? `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` , `sudo a2enmod proxy`,

Comment: si tengo proxy_http, proxy, proxy_wstunnel habilitados

Comment: intenta un telnet tuip puerto , para verificar si no son permisos del servidor